# Setting up Rails app with angular2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular

I am new to Angular2. I am trying to integrate Angular2 with rails for increasing app performance and modularity. I used angular-rails-templates gem with rails4 but now I am trying to update Angular1.5 to Angular2.Can any one help me out for replacing angular-rails-templates gem with other or steps to integrate manually with webpack or with any other options.

Comment: Are you asking for someone to handhold you through the process or do you have some specific problem?

Comment: Now, I didn't have idea where to start which way is best. If someone helps me to choose a best away by replacing gem or alternative way by giving references by blogs or some git repos that would be great.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't for helping you decide on a "best" approach, but rather, to help you when you have a specific programming issue that you can't solve on your own. Please consult the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the SO help files for more information on asking good questions which receive good answers.

Comment: @DineshPallapa what happened? Did you solve the problem? I think many AngularJS and Rails app might have used this angular-rails-templates gem, but it's surprisingly hard to find resources about upgrading to webpacker.

Comment: You can try with webpacker gem with rails